# Custom Campaign Member URL button Lead Conversion

Tags: visualforce, lead-conversion, campaign-member, custom-url

I have created a custom lead conversion process. Now I have a requirement to add that custom process to campaign members.

To do that I created a URL Detail Page Button. I thought what I did would work but I got the following error :

> Id value is not valid for the Lead standard controller

I'm wondering if instead of the `{!Lead.Id}` I should use something like `00Q`.

I'm trying to get this to work and I've tried several fixes and tried making it a javascript button too. How can I get this to pull the lead ID out of the campaign member? Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
/apex/leadConvertPage?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Campaign Member Javascript Button Help](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69611/campaign-member-javascript-button-help)

Comment: @JimRae This question is different because it is a URL link button. The other question was asking why the Javascript was sending me to a page with an additional convert button instead of straight to the conversion screen. In this URL one I'm trying to figure out why it is not grabbing the id.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was a dumb question. I had Lead.Id instead of Campaignmember.LeadId. Here is what I ended up with.

```
/apex/leadConvertPage?retURL=%2F{!CampaignMember.LeadId}&id={!CampaignMember.LeadId}
```